# I would like to quickly console log the response from this API in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-services

So I have setup this **service** to console log the response from a News API like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsApiService {
  private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArticles() {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

This is something temporary I would like to do until I get up to speed with RxJS Observables, but I am getting nothing in the console and absolutely no error anywhere.

Comment: I just tried calling this function from another component and it worked. Are you sure you are calling this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because inside your `NewsApiService > getArticles` you are subscribing to the call from you HTTP request instead of returning the result.

Attached herewith is the **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-service-demo?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference. You can check the **`console`** tab

---

Your **NewsApiService** should be like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class NewsApiService {
  private url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getArticles(): Observable<any> {                  // Add the return type to be Observable 
                                                    // and you can change the <any> to your own type
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private newsService: NewsApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newsService
      .getArticles()
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));         // Log the result from service

  }
}
```

Comment: okay so there is no getting around having to access an `Observable` from **rxjs**. Thank you.